# React application gets logged out of safari seconds after logging in but working fine with chrome and other browsers

Tags: reactjs

```
export const userLogout = async (countryId: number) => {
  window.stop()
  await axiosInstance.post(API_URL[countryId] + "/account/logout", {
    withCredentials: true
  });
  clearUserCache();
};
```

This is logOut function
please tell me how can I handle it

Comment: Need a bit more information, how do you keep the user logged in? Do you store a token in cookies or localstorage or indexdb. This will help clear up the problem.

Comment: i store token in localstrorage